# HammerDB: what does 'Number of Warehouses' mean?

Tags: database, benchmarking, tpc, hammerdb

In HammerDB in schema building there is an option named 'Number of Warehouses'.
But the meaning of this term is unclear. I mean I know what 'warehouse' IS, but I don't understand what it MEANS in context of DB creation.

Could anyone explain this term with simple words, please? Don't get me wrong))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's value to meassure performance of a database. It's used for the TPC-C benchmark test. One Warehouse is a Warehouse with 100.000 items, 10 sales districts and each district serves 3,000 customers.

For further informationen:
https://houseofbrick.com/blog/benchmarking-transaction-databases/

Comment: Excuse me, could not answer earlier. Thanks a lot for this, it helped to build benchmark script))